# I’d like to create an okta integration for our customers to call our api and block login if required

Tags: authentication, auth0, okta

we’re looking to build out an Okta integration that will become part of our customers flow. We want to be able to call our api with details from our customers okta login. We’ll pass these details to our api and do our business logic to either approve or deny the log in attempt. If denied we’d like to provide some details about why. Would anyone be able to point me in the right direct for achieving this?

I’ve been playing around with okta and auth0 without much luck.